# Can we able to Split PDF files using Pig Udfs?

Tags: apache-pig, pdf-parsing, pig-udf

I have 100 pdf's but each pdf's have 40 pages, i.e.. it's not processed. Actually, we are trying to use pig Udf?? Can we able to Split PDF files using Pig Udf??

Answer (score 0):

No. While I am not intimately familiar with Pig, it does not seem to natively understand the PDF file format and is meant for storing and analyzing data, not manipulating files.

You may be able to combine Pig with another library that understands PDF in order to split the PDFs, Pig is not a requirement though to split a PDF, it all depends on what the workflow/purpose of using Pig is.